# Struggling to get a CSV Report to load when requested

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, sidekiq

I'm trying to make it possible to view a report from a webpage and I am struggling. This task uses Sidekiq.

When I click on the link that should take me there I get the error: "The action `'churn_risk_report'` could not be found for `Admin::ReportsController`."

In a show.html.erb file, in the Reports view, I've added `<li><%= link_to 'Churn Risk Report', churn_risk_report_admin_reports_path %></li>` beneath a number of similar lines with links to other reports.

I've added `get 'churn_risk_report'` in the correct place in my Routes file.

In my Workers directory, which I believe is my system's version of a Scripts directory used for Sidekiq jobs, I have a file called `churn_risk_report.rb` and in this file I have the following code:

```
class ChurnRiskReport
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    csv_temp = Tempfile.new
    puts csv_temp.path
    CSV.open(csv_temp.path, 'wb') do |csv|

      csv << ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF"]

      AccountChurnRisk.all.each do |acr|
        report_data = [acr.aaa,
        acr.bbb,
        "#{acr.ccc} #{acr.ccc}",
        acr.ddd,
        acr.eee,
        acr.fff]

        csv << report_data
      end
    end

    report_name = "churn_risk_report"
    file_name = "gggggggggg-#{report_name}-#{DateTime.now.to_date.strftime("%b-%Y")}.csv".downcase
    bucket_name = 'hhh-reports'
    s3 = AWS::S3.new
    key = "reports/churn_reports/" + File.basename(file_name)
    x = s3.buckets[bucket_name].objects[key].write(:file => csv_temp.path)
  end

end
```

Consecutive letters = code that I think should be kept private. This code worked in a rails console when I ran it, so I know the code works.

I'm struggling with the final part of the task. In the Reports controller I've defined `churn_risk_report` and just copied in the same code as is in the Worker file. I know this is incorrect but I'm not sure what should go in there. I think there should be some code in here that temporarily creates a `churn_risk_report` file in the Workers directory, however this might not be the case. I also think that 'async' should be involved somewhere.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: From the error message, the issue is relating to the controller/routes. Can you show the relevant parts of those?

Comment: Hello.

Yes they are as follows. In the routes.rb file I have:
```resource :reports, only: [:show] do
      ...
      get 'churn_risk_report'
      ...
    end```

And in the controller file I have:
```def churn_risk_report
    ...
    (NOT ENOUGH SPACE TO WRITE IT ALL IN. EVERYTHING BENEATH "include Sidekiq::Worker" and above the third "end" in the original question)
    ...
    end

Please let me know if I've misunderstood your comment and these are not the bits of code you were talking about. Thanks, again :)

Comment: So, can you verify that the class `Admin::ReportsController` does in fact have a `churn_risk_report` method? By the way, you can edit your question to add code ... don't need to fit it into a comment ..

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that. Just to be sure, ```Admin::ReportsController``` denotes the report_controller.rb file that is in my Admin directory doesn't it? If so then yes there it does have a churn_risk_report method.

Comment: It's not just the file name. You have to define the class like that too.

Comment: Yeah sorry, didn't explain myself well there. 
"class Admin::ReportsController < Admin::AdminController
...
end" I have this in the reports_controller.rb file, in which methods for every report we run are defined, including churn_risk_report

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of this answer, is the gist I keep specifically for basic CSV export logic handling works for most cases that don't require high performance. Typically I use it as a way for the user to download a CSV copy of the data they are *currently* looking at (so caching in S3 isn't overly practical): https://gist.github.com/MyklClason/f6ac68ca4ce1faa5d655abfb0abe788b

Depending on how large the report is, saving it in S3 may be excessive, but could work as a way to cache it (or store it for long term). In which case before rendering the download link (to the S3 file itself), you check to see if the report already exists, if it does, render a link directly to AWS, if it doesn't, render a "generate report" link, then once the report is generated, render a "Download report" link.

Even better if you can auto-generate the reports, which seems to be what you are doing in the original code. Though I think a "Generate report" button could queue up the job to run the code you have though likely the reports are monthly or something so you know exactly when you need to create them, in which case the "Generate report" button probably isn't needed and you can just provide an S3 download link, if the report has been generated.

Gist content:

```
# Good solution for exporting to CSV in rails.
# Source: https://www.codementor.io/victorhazbun/export-records-to-csv-files-ruby-on-rails-vda8323q0

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @users.to_csv, filename: "users-#{Date.today}.csv" }
    end
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.to_csv
    attributes = %w{id email name}

    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << attributes

      all.each do |user|
        csv << attributes.map{ |attr| user.send(attr) }
      end
    end
  end
end

<%= link_to 'Export CSV', user_path(format: :csv) %>
```